# Performance issue in Hibernate while executing the procedure

Tags: java, hibernate

I am unable to find out why procedure is taking 7 seconds when invoked from Hibernate code. Where as when same procedure is executed directly in sql developer, it is taking only 3 secs.

Following is my code

```
 Statistics stats = template.getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
     stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);

      LOGGER.debug( "Thread [", java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName(),
     "] Going to execute procedure/function [", this.fullProcName, "] with
     input ", inputMap.toString() );

     Map resultsVED1 = sp1.call( policyId, policyVO.getNewEndtId(),
     SvcUtils.getUserId( policyVO ), GEN_SECTION_ID, LOC_ID );

     LOGGER.debug( "Thread [", java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getName(),
     "] Got result from procedure/function [", this.fullProcName, "] as ",
     result.toString() );

     stats.logSummary();
```

The template in the above code snippet is Hibernate template. 
1. I am enabling the hibernate statistics, 
2. logging the start time and 
3. then calling the procedure with some parameters, 
4. logging the procedure end time and 
5. then logging the statistics.

I have enabled statistics only for this block of code in the entire application.

Result :

```
[8/18/15 11:48:42:565 GST] Going to execute procedure pro_endt_text_policy ..
[8/18/15 11:48:49:049 GST] Got result from procedure pro_endt_text_policy] as 
StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary Logging statistics
org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary start time: 1439810953283
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:049 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary sessions opened: 269
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary sessions closed: 249
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary transactions: 249
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary successful transactions: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary optimistic lock failures: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary flushes: 295
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary connections obtained: 269
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary statements prepared: 1924
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:065 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary statements closed: 1924
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary second level cache puts: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary second level cache hits: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary second level cache misses: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary entities loaded: 2511
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary entities updated: 37
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary entities inserted: 23
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary entities deleted: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:080 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary entities fetched (minimize this): 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary collections loaded: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary collections updated: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary collections removed: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary collections recreated: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary collections fetched (minimize this): 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary queries executed to database: 1792
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary query cache puts: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:096 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary query cache hits: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:111 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary query cache misses: 0
        [8/18/15 11:48:49:111 GST] 0000003b StatisticsImp I org.hibernate.stat.StatisticsImpl logSummary max query time: 2234ms
```

The start time and end time difference between procedure execution is around 7 secs ..But statistics from Hibernate says 2.3 secs (max query time: 2234ms).
**So where is remaining time gone when this procedure is executed ? How will I can get this procedure executed fast from the application ?**

Things I have tried.
1. I have run the trace to check this procedure but trace also shows query being executed under 3 seconds.
2. I have commented procedure body and invoked procedure from code and it is taking negligible time to execute.(I have done this to check if calling of procedure itself is slow.)

I am using Hibernate 3 and database is 12 c.

Can you please give pointers to how can I proceed working towards  reducing procedure execution time.

Comment: Did you try using a profiler?

Comment: No..I didn't try using profiler..I will try that..